# How to create custom authentication in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

How to create custom authentication in laravel 8 with a preexisting table (but with table name Users_system not Users) and this table (Users_system) is full of data and does not have the same fields as Users for laravel?

Comment: Welcome to SO .. .you can create your own auth system based on `session` or `cookies` and create own middleware to protect

Answer (score 1):

For beginners in Laravel who want to set up an admin panel or dashboard with mail based authentication and basic CMS features WITHOUT using any Laravel packages. AdminLTE default integrated. Just download LaraShade from: https://github.com/agni-s-chakraborty/larashade

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to have same fields in your database. If you want to create a new model for new table, create UserSystem model and replace all the `App\User` instances with `App\UserSystem` model.

If you want to use existing model, just change the table name in the `App\User` model.

If you have different user name or any authentication credentials, you need to move `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` class code to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`.

Following are the code segments that you need to change there.

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}

//Mention your username here
public function username()
{
    return 'user_name';
}
```